Unable to find any RPC peers
I set up an RPC node following the suggestions on the official docs, the launch script looks like this.
#!/bin/bash
export RUST_BACKTRACE=1
export RUST_LOG=solana=info
exec solana-validator \
  --identity /home/solana/.config/solana/id.json \
  --entrypoint entrypoint.mainnet-beta.solana.com:8001 \
  --entrypoint entrypoint2.mainnet-beta.solana.com:8001 \
  --entrypoint entrypoint3.mainnet-beta.solana.com:8001 \
  --entrypoint entrypoint4.mainnet-beta.solana.com:8001 \
  --entrypoint entrypoint5.mainnet-beta.solana.com:8001 \
  --known-validator 5D1fNXzvv5NjV1ysLjirC4WY92RNsVH18vjmcszZd8on \
  --known-validator dDzy5SR3AXdYWVqbDEkVFdvSPCtS9ihF5kJkHCtXoFs \
  --known-validator eoKpUABi59aT4rR9HGS3LcMecfut9x7zJyodWWP43YQ \
  --known-validator 7XSY3MrYnK8vq693Rju17bbPkCN3Z7KvvfvJx4kdrsSY \
  --known-validator Ft5fbkqNa76vnsjYNwjDZUXoTWpP7VYm3mtsaQckQADN \
  --known-validator 9QxCLckBiJc783jnMvXZubK4wH86Eqqvashtrwvcsgkv \
  --rpc-port 8899 \
  --dynamic-port-range 8802-8816 \
  --no-port-check \
  --gossip-port 8001 \
  --no-os-network-limits-test \
  --no-untrusted-rpc \
  --no-voting \
  --private-rpc \
  --rpc-bind-address 0.0.0.0 \
  --enable-cpi-and-log-storage \
  --enable-rpc-transaction-history \
  --enable-rpc-bigtable-ledger-storage \
  --no-duplicate-instance-check \
  --wal-recovery-mode skip_any_corrupted_record \
  --log /home/solana/.logs/rpc-node \
  --accounts /var/solana/accounts \
  --ledger /var/solana/data/ledger \
  --limit-ledger-size 100_000_000 \
  --rpc-send-default-max-retries 30 \
  --rpc-send-service-max-retries 30 \
  --rpc-send-retry-ms 2000 \
  --full-rpc-api

I noticed after I perform a restart the process spends a lot of time (several minutes) stuck on this message

[2024-10-21T15:36:14.912202575Z INFO  solana_validator::bootstrap]
Searching for an RPC service with shred version 50093 (Retrying: Wait
for known rpc peers)...


[2024-10-21T15:36:14.912418814Z INFO
solana_validator::bootstrap] Total 0 RPC nodes found. 0 known, 0
blacklisted

In some cases, I even get this error

[2024-10-21T15:38:26.313727162Z ERROR solana_validator::bootstrap]
Failed to get RPC nodes: Unable to find any RPC peers. Consider
checking system clock, removing --no-port-check, or adjusting
--known-validator ... arguments as applicable

Googling around, it seems this can be improved by changing the list of known-validators, however I am using those suggested in the official docs so I would assume they're some of the best. Also, I tried changing for some others but the result is unchanged, the node still spends a lot of time waiting to find a suitable RPC node. Does this have anything to do with my configuration? I might be wrong, but I assume the time spent searching for nodes is time my own node is not actually receiving time, so the data will be delayed. Because I am going to use this node to receive real time block data, that would be a problem.

I think the issue is those known-validators are testnet validators. Used a bunch of addresses from the top validators and now it's finding peers much faster.
